# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python

my code:

```
def média_harmonica(x,y):
    média_harmonica = 2/((1/x)+(1/y))
    return média_harmonica

x = float(input("Informe um número para x: "))
y = float(input("Informe um número para y: "))

média_harmonica = (2/((1/x)+(1/y)))
mensagem = "A média harmonica de "+x+" e "+y+" é: "+float(média_harmonica)
print(mensagem)
```

Comment: `média_harmonica` is already a `float`, so if you want to print it, just do `+str(média_harmonica)` instead of `+float(média_harmonica)`.

Comment: You can use "f" strings: `mensagem = f"A média harmonica de {x} e {y} é: {média_harmonica}"`

Comment: it works thank u guys sm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you cannot concatenate a float to a string. You can add that variable to the string in a few ways:

1. F-strings:
   `mensagem = f"A média harmonica de {x} e {y} é: {média_harmonica}"`
2. casting: `mensagem = "A média harmonica de " + str(x) + " e " + str(y) + " é:" + str(média_harmonica)`